# working on 4.0.3 and 4.1 but Error on 2.1,2.2 and 2.3 - Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I was following one SIMPLE tutorial of Sherlock Action Bar. I followed each and every step. The problem is I'm getting error on versions 2.1 to 2.3 and working fine on 4.0 to 4.1.
I'm using **Android SDK tools 20.0.3 And Eclipse version 4.2.0**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

In above code it says `R cannot be resolved to a variable`.
and some more errors are as follows:

```
 [2012-09-04 22:18:21 - Action Bar demo] C:\Users\Karthick\Desktop\Project libs\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-88fc341\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
    [2012-09-04 22:18:21 - Action Bar demo] C:\Users\Karthick\Desktop\Project libs\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-88fc341\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
    [2012-09-04 22:18:21 - Action Bar demo] C:\Users\Karthick\Desktop\Project libs\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-88fc341\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
    [2012-09-04 22:18:21 - Action Bar demo] C:\Users\Karthick\Desktop\Project libs\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-88fc341\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
```

For better understanding, here are some images:

[image]

[image]

My manifest file is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.action.bar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Google"></activity>
</application>
```

*Somebody assist me in fixing these errors in Android 2.3*

**The same code is working fine in Android 4.0.3**

Comment: I think @Kaediil is correct: change the build target of your project back to 4.0.3 or later. The reason `R` cannot be resolved is because your resources will not compile due to the Holo theme related styles that weren't available in Gingerbread. The build target has nothing to do with what devices your app will be compatible with; that's all defined in the manifest with min/maxSdkVersion.

Comment: @MH so here is the screenshot http://twitpic.com/ar41l2/full for Android 4.0.3. No errors!!

Comment: @MH And what should I do with Holo theme related styles?? Will it work on 2.3 devices by setting Android project to 4.0.3??

Comment: Don't use the Holo themes and styles directly, but use the themes provided by ActionBarSherlock. That will default to the native resources on ICS+, but the included ones on older platforms. Do note that ABS only backports the Holo themes/styles required for the ActionBar. Have a look at the HoloEverwhere project for a full backport.

Comment: Thank you Mr.@MH.I understood now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is I'm getting error on versions 2.1 to 2.3 and working
>   fine on 4.0 to 4.1.

=> As you have mentioned this is working fine in 4.0 and 4.1 but not in 2.x version, i am sure you forgot include compatible ActionBarSherlock theme in your style.xml:

If you haven't included **styles.xml** with below values, then do it:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

As you have mentioned above about **values-v11 and values-v14** for styles.xml, you can create styles.xml in both the folder with below values:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused when I look at your screen shot.  First, your project should be using Android 4.0.3, not 2.3 in the Android libraries.  You already cover 2.3 with the minSDKVersion line in your manifest.  Second I can't quite tell, but I assume that in the properties for your project, you made your main project be dependent upon the ActionBarSherlock library?

Comment: Yeah I used using Android 4.0.3 and there was no errors in the project. Then I changed my build target to Android 2.3.3 to support Gingerbread devices.You said that "You already cover 2.3 with the minSDKVersion line in your manifest." My doubt is that will it work on 2.3 devices without changing build target to Android 2.3???

Comment: Yes, it will work on 2.3 devices as long as you do not use any API calls that are not in 2.3.