# How to make ActionBar Compatibility with 2.3.3 version?

Tags: android

well my program runs perfectly on 4.0 & above version,

i'm using **ActionBarShrelock** Library to do this .

when i changed the target to 2.3.3 
    `target=android-10`

it's giving error at "R.id.home".

```
switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
        Log.d("home","home selected");
        slidemenu.show();
        return true;
    }
```

even i have changed the style to :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

but if i change the target usage :
    `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`

it works in 2.3 as well as in 4.0 and above ,but the problem is the visuality differs.

output of 4.0 is as shown below.

[image]

output of 2.3.3 is as shown below.
[image]

Any idea how to fix this issue.?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html. check the para before Removing the action bar in the link

Comment: post ur manifest file

Answer (score 5):

ActionBar requires a **higher API level** and that is why it is not working on 2.3.3.

**[ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)** was introduced in API level 11, i.e. **Android 3.0**.

To use ActionBar in API levels **lower** than that, you can use **[ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)**.

Comment: i'm using ActionBarSherlock Library.

Comment: @Alex : I don't really think it is possible. Check the documentation for ActionBar. It was introduced in 3.0. So, I don't really think that it would be possible to use it in 2.3.3.

Comment: @Uday : You are getting the error on using ActionBarSherlock ?

Comment: @Uday : In that case, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12274573/1393623

Comment: @swayam What not possible?

Comment: @Alex : I meant that is not possible to do so without using the external library. The OP is using an external library. I thought he was not, because he had mentioned nothing about it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest put `targetSdk="17"` (anyway, put the highest possible) and `minSdk="8"`

Actually, copy those values from any ABS examples which come with Sherlock.

Comment: well it works if i change.
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
but not exactly as in 4.0 & above.

Comment: Not exactly you mean visually differs? This maybe because they use a different theme. Try other sherlock themes. In Sherlock examples they have different themes set in values-11 values-14 etc

Comment: well i have posted the image above , check it out once.
i have added the shrelock theam in values-11 & values-14.

Comment: I've never seen ActionBar icon on the right before. Maybe your language is from right to left? I've heard they added support for such languages in later Android versions. Otherwise I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Nope it's on left only i'm using Slide menu actionbar so,
when u click on ActionBar icon it will slide to right.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the theme in manifest  as `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`

Answer (score 0):

```
it's giving error at "R.id.home".
```

it seems like there may be problem with imports , will you check your imports

Following import is for `ActionBar`

```
 com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar
```

Following import is for `Menu`

```
 com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu
 com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem
 com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater
```